# Issues running Matplotlib/PyQt- Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am having problems with my matplotlib/Pyqt. I have tried several different things like uninstalling matplotlib using conda remove and pip uninstall and then tried re-installing. When I try re-installing matplotlib through conda reinstall, I get the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\Anaconda2\pkgs\pandas-0.19.2-np111py27_1\info\index.json'

I seem to be able to install matplotlib via pip install, but when I try running my code in jupyter notbook I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named PyQt4.

Any suggestions? I am using Python version 2.7.13 and Anaconda version 4.0.0 (64-bit) windows operator.

Comment: have you tried **pip install pyqt** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Anaconda try this :

```
conda clean --packages --tarballs
conda update qt
```

or just Re-install it.

Finally, Don't forget to install PyQt4:

```
pip install PyQt4
```

or download the python Wheel pkg from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4

& install it by:

```
pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```